# Loading an image from a chrome extension on a page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've got some images in my chrome extension that I want the user to be able to inject into their page when they are using the extension.

The images will show up in the extension pop-up window, but when the user clicks the button to inject them into the page, the page can't access them/see them for some reason. I know there are specific ways of injecting JS and CSS into the page (already doing that) but I don't see any way to do the same thing with images.

I've got the following permissions set in my manifest (added the chrome-extensions:// one hoping that would do it):

```
"permissions" : [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "chrome-extension://*/*" ]
```

Specifically, I'm trying to change the favicon, kind of like this (I've also tried without the leading /, and with chrome.extension.getURL("favicons/example.png")):

```
  iconURL = "/favicons/example.png";
  var link = document.createElement("link");
  link.type = "image/x-icon";
  link.rel = "shortcut icon";
  link.href = iconURL;
  this.removeLinkIfExists();
  this.docHead.appendChild(link);
```

This code works perfectly if the iconURL is a fully qualified http:// address...

You can see the actual code at my [github repo here](https://github.com/cmcculloh/Tab-Edit) (favicon.js line 54, called by tabdisplay.js line 260).

Comment: Accessing files from the extension should be granted by default. How are you trying to load them, and what types of error messages (if there are) are you getting?

Comment: No errors, just, nothing happens. It just sits there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of:

```
iconURL = "/favicons/example.png";
```

It should be:

```
iconURL = chrome.extension.getURL("/favicons/example.png");
```

which returns absolute URL to a file inside extension folder.

Also remove `chrome-extension://*/*` from manifest as it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @cmcculloh Hm, you are right it doesn't work, but it should. If you try to inject icon as an `<img>` tag to a page it works, while inside `<link>` tag it doesn't. This looks like a chrome bug.

Comment: I removed the first / and it works fine. Don't forget to add it in your authorized web ressources in the manifest.

Answer (score 23):

In case people are having this problem on Chrome 17 or later, it's because the manifest must include the web_accessible_resources section to allow an image packed within the extension to be injected into a web page.
**[web accessible resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/)**

Comment: YES! This was the problem I had, thank you so much! :D

Comment: Outdated answer, broken link

Answer (score 5):

You can use from CSS as well, make sure to add this image into manifest as well.

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
```

inside CSS:

```
background-image: url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/image.png");
```

Comment: what is __MSG__?

Comment: @maxgalbu I have forgotten why it added. But I think to get chrome extension url. or you can even try `chrome.extension.getURL`

Comment: Tried it and it works, i was thinking it was some kind of constant to be replaced

Comment: What's in "web_accessible_resources"?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to add an image from the extension into a web page, there are security measures that do not allow directly using a `chrome://` url to load things like images.

A solution I can think of is to encode the image into a data uri and sending it as text then using that as the src of the img.

```
  iconURL = "/favicons/example.png";
  var link = document.createElement("link");
  link.type = "image/x-icon";
  link.rel = "shortcut icon";
  //convert iconURL into data uri (data:image/png;base64,...)
  link.href = iconURL;
  this.removeLinkIfExists();
  this.docHead.appendChild(link);
```

However, the only way I can think of to do that conversion is using a canvas element.

Answer (score 0):

The [STEEL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/942317/steel) answer is Ok but limited, if you want to introduce an image in the document, not as background of a div, you can do as follow.

```html
<img id="divId" src="chrome-extension://__MSG_@@some_Chrome_Extension_Id/path/image.png">
```

in the manifest file you does need include.

"web_accessible_resources": ["image.png","anotherImage.png"]

Comment: __MSG_@@ could be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

2 things needs to happen to display an image from an extension package onto a webpage:

First, it must be authorized to be accessed. Add the following to your manifest.json file:

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "images/rating-yes.png", "images/rating-no.png" ],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
```

Second, you need to access the image via a special URL, as STEEL's answer pointed out:

```
background-image: url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/rating-yes.png");
```